# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise : No tasks to display. (windows 7)

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

C#, .net 4.7
Debug => tasks shows : "No tasks to display."
Can anyone confirm it is supposed to work on windows 7 ?
Thx

Comment: Hi friend, if my reply is helpful to solve your question, Could you please mark it as answer, which can be beneficial to other community members. It can be easier for them to search the solution. Also, if this issue persists, feel free to contact me with further info. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> First, the Task Window in Debug mode can work on window7.

I spend some time configuring the environment.(windows7 and .net4.7) to confirm it.
Steps: Create a new C# console app(.net framework). And add the code below:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)        **//line11**
        {                                      **//line12**
            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                // Just loop.
                int ctr = 0;
                for (ctr = 0; ctr <= 1000000; ctr++)
                { }
                Console.WriteLine("Finished {0} loop iterations",ctr);
            });
            t.Wait();
        }
```

1.Add the break point to line12 and start Debugging,nothing in Task window

2.Step into(F11), still nothing

3.Step into(F11), main task with ID 1 will display

> In addition,I think you can get some help from [this
>   document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-tasks-window?view=vs-2017).

It introduces the usage of Task window in debug and for managed code like C#, Task window only works with [System.Threading.Tasks.Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.7.2) objects or with the **await** and **async** keywords (**Await** and **Async** in VisualBasic)

In C#,the task window is designed to work with task object. For those program without using the task object, this option won't work. And i think it may be the cause of your issue.